# Word for "person living with in-laws" or "feeling awkward and inadequate"

Tags: word-choice, synonyms, kinship-terms

Is there a word for a *Person living with in-law parents*, by which I mean, a man or a woman who got married and moved to his or her parents in laws' house, in English ?

There is a word for it in my native tongue, which is specifically used to express a constant feeling of discomfort caused by social inadequacy.

I would like to know a suitable synonym for the word itself or the expression.

(For search indexing purposes, the word is: içgüveyisi)

Comment: There's no such succinct word that I'm aware of, but there are expressions for the awkward feeling of intruding and feeling out-of-place, such as being a "bump on a log", a "bull in a china shop", a "5th wheel", although the last one really is more for someone who tags along when the rest of group is paired up with dates.

Comment: There is a cute 1966 film [*The Family Way*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0060395/?ref_=fn_al_tt_4) depicting a newly married couple struggling with this status. It starred Haley Mills in one of her first adult roles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***live-in son-in-law*** is one alternative. [LDOCE](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/live-in) as an instance among the other dictionaries has this entry:

> **live-in lover/boyfriend etc**    someone who lives with their sexual partner but is not married to them

And *live-in son-in-law* can be quite explanatory based on that.

Another word you could use is ***freeloader son-in-law***.

However, there won't be a better word for this in English, since this is something cultural, and that type of person isn't all that much seen around these days among English speakers.

It's interesting to notice that the movie *Meet Bill* is translated as [İçgüveyisi Bill](http://tr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C4%B0%C3%A7g%C3%BCveysi_Bill) which is a perfect translation, but as I checked IMDB and the English Wikipedia, I couldn't find a *word* for the character Bill in that film.

Comment: I also notice Aziz Nesin has a short story called "içgüveyisi" but I cannot find any articles about it; it'd be helpful to see how they've translated it to English if I could.

Comment: +1 for "freeloader son-in-law" though that's probably how the in-laws feel, not the son-in-law. lol!

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a word for Person living with in-law parents, by which I mean, a man or woman who got married and moved to his or her parents in laws' house, in English ?

No, there is not. (But you can make one up, if you like.)

Comment: Actually, it **does** answer the question.

Comment: Yes, this **is** the only (honest) answer to the question (*Is there a word...in English?*) - whether one likes it or not. That will be seen eventually, after various silly attempts to coin a synonym have been exhibited here shamelessly. (And this answer is flagged for deletion. Sheesh.)

Comment: @Drew sorry that happened to you for expressing your conviction.

Comment: @nurettin: Nothing happened to me. Deleting the answer and leaving a bunch of invented-synonym (& multiple-word, for *Is there a word?*) pseudo-answers does not help S.E. users, that's all. At least you (the OP) got a chance to see the message.